# Fastest Python way to compare two dirs and delete non-duplicate basenames

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, string-comparison, shutil

I have two directories, one called `images` and one called `annotations`. In the images directory I have images with long string names and the `.jpg` file extension. In the annotations directory I have `.xml` files with the same string names (up to the extension).

I removed a bunch of xml files (approx 20k out of 200k), but I still have all 200k images. Now I want to remove the image files that no longer have a corresponding xml file. I can do this easily by globbing each directory and comparing every pair in each file list, but this will take quite a bit of time to run. Is there any faster way to go about this?

So in other words what's the fastest way in python to compare list A and sublist  B, then return all non matches from A?

Comment: Is there any structure to file names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `pathlib` library and `set` data structure as follows.

```
from pathlib import Path
keep_stems = set(p.stem for p in Path('images').glob('*.jpg'))
delete_paths = [p for p in Path('annotations').glob('*.xml') if p.stem not in keep_stems]
for p in delete_paths:
    p.unlink()
```

You could technically just do the unlink in the list comprehension but having side-effects from a list comprehension seems unpleasant.

Comment: yeah just did this I should have realized to use sets earlier, thanks

Comment: this is backwards though btw, assumes images is a subset of annotations. thanks for using pathlib too, gota switch to this instead of os/glob

Comment: Oh my mistake, but glad it helped.